# Cut Everything After "-" and ":" in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, ssis

I receive third-party data every month in the form of an Excel spreadsheet and I have an SSIS package to import into SQL Server. however I have two fields that I need to cut before inserting the data into the table.  The first field I want to cut everything including and after a ":" and the second field I need to cut everything including and after a "/".  I know exactly what I want to do but am unfamiliar with the syntax.  May someone point me in the right direction?

The following are example of what needs to be cut:

```
 A999/8888
 1234567-11111:2ZCV4
```

I want it to just be `A999` and `1234567-11111`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cut everything to the right of and including '-':

```
SELECT LEFT(ColumnName, CHARINDEX('-', ColumnName) - 1)
FROM ExampleTable
```

To cut everything to the right of and including '/':

```
SELECT LEFT(ColumnName, CHARINDEX('/',ColumnName) - 1)
FROM ExampleTable
```